# Filling a space with equal spacing lines

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have the following C# code:

```
int cellHeight = (int)Math.Floor((ClientSize.Height - controlsSpacing) / 25f);

int yStart = MarginSize + controlsSpacing;
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0 + MarginSize, yStart, ClientSize.Width - MarginSize - 1,
                    cellHeight);
    yStart += cellHeight;
}
```

What I am trying to do is draw 25 lines that extend from the top to the bottom and are equally spaced out to fit into the `ClientSize` area. The problem I have is that the last line drawn always seems to be smaller or larger then the rest of them. My math must be failing somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a small screenshot?

Comment: dtb - Just added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
int cellHeight = (int)Math.Floor(..)
yStart += cellHeight;
```

The fraction that you remove by using `Math.Floor` is missing in each iteration and accumulates to the gap you see.

Calculate `yStart` in each iteration:

```
int cellHeight = (int);

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    float yStart = MarginSize + controlsSpacing +
                 (ClientSize.Height - controlsSpacing) * i / 25f;

    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                    MarginSize,
                    yStart,
                    ClientSize.Width - MarginSize - 1,
                    cellHeight);
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. By moving `yStart` into my loop and recalculating it each iteration, as you suggested, fixed my problem and all 25 lines are even now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make cellHeight and yStart doubles, and convert them to ints in the call the DrawRectangle. You may need to do Math.Round() rather than just casting to an int.

```
double cellHeight = (ClientSize.Height - controlsSpacing) / 25.0;

double yStart = MarginSize + controlsSpacing;

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0 + MarginSize, (int)yStart, ClientSize.Width - MarginSize - 1,
                    (int)cellHeight);
    yStart += cellHeight;
}
```

Comment: Same issue Matthew. All the lines are equal except for that stupid bottom line

Comment: Hmm, I think you're drawing 25 lines, but there are only 24 gaps, so you should be dividing by 24.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just edited my code and fixed it. The last line is still wrong though. I uploaded a screen shot

Comment: I see you have it fixed now, but I think I can see the final error: You were not accounting for MarginSize in your first calculation of cellHeight. You needed to subtract that too.